# Check for null before applying a logic in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am currently performing below operation. I need to check if x is null before performing any mathematical operation on the column in a dataframe. Please let me know how it can be achieved ?

```
df['converted_value'] = df['main_value'].apply(lambda x: (float(x)/10000) * 350000)
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample? Also why not use `df['converted_value'] = (df['main_value'] /10000) * 350000)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "null", I'm not sure if you mean `None` or `NaN` (as in `np.nan`, which is a float).

If you mean `None`:

`df['converted_value'] = df['main_value'].apply(lambda x: (x/10000) * 350000 if x is not None else None)`

If you mean `NaN` (`np.nan`), then what you have should return `NaN` for `NaN` input already, but, as suggested in the comments, you could do a column operation instead in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Your function working with `NaN`s very nice, faster is vectorized alternative:

```
df['converted_value'] = (df['main_value'] /10000) * 350000)
```

---

One possible solution is filtering only non missing values and apply function:

```
mask = df['main_value'].notna()
f = lambda x: function_not_working_with_nan(x)
df.loc[mask, 'converted_value'] = df.loc[mask, 'main_value'].apply(f)
```